# Dynamics CRM : Difference between Site and Sales Territory

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I am creating organization architecture in dynamics CRM.

I have one question regarding - Site vs Sales Territory
or BU vs Site
When exactly we should create Site, Sales Territory or BU ?

Or we can say what are the limitations of them  ?

I have gone through many forums and websites but not able to find any good document on this.

Any online book which I can read to understand this difference ?

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Mittal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are all quite different things used for different purposes. You may find you will need all three or just a couple depending on what you are trying to do. E.g. If you are not doing any sales you wont need sales territories, if you want to model a security model where only some users can see some data you will want business units.

I would suggest digging into each area in more detail (scheduling, sales, security) as described below to make that decision.

[Sites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328476.aspx) are part of the scheduling engine.

> In Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011, a site entity represents a location or
>   branch office where an organization does business. Many Microsoft
>   Dynamics CRM customers have multiple sites. Sites enable resources,
>   services, and appointments to be defined at a particular location with
>   an associated time zone. Location, correct selection of resources, and
>   time zone are important elements in the scheduling of service
>   appointments when multiple locations of doing business are involved.
>   You can use sites to limit what resources, such as users and
>   equipment, can be scheduled for a specific service activity.
>
> When you search for an available service activity resource calendar
>   time slot, to avoid making an appointment in the wrong location, the
>   scheduler must be able to select the site or delivery location as a
>   constraint to the search. For example, a customer may ask for an
>   appointment at the Seattle office. To support this, there must be a
>   site named Seattle and there must be required resources assigned to
>   the service type to be performed. When generating appointment
>   proposals, Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 must be able to avoid proposing
>   appointments with resources that cannot physically be together to
>   provide the service. The site entity serves this purpose. Sites
>   provide for the grouping of resources, such as users and
>   facility/equipment, services, and appointments, according to a
>   location with an associated time zone and locale.

[Sales Territories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328022.aspx) are part of the sales process.

> Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 uses the fiscal calendar entities and the
>   territory entity to track sales information for a salesperson. A
>   salesperson is a user in Microsoft Dynamics CRM who has to meet sales
>   objectives, such as sales quotas. A territory is a geographical area
>   that is assigned to a salesperson.

[Business Units](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309617.aspx) are part of the security model.

> An organization in Microsoft Dynamics CRM, such as a holding company
>   or a corporation, is made up of business units. A business unit is a
>   unit of the top-level organization. Business units can be parents of
>   other business units (child business units). The first business unit
>   created for an organization is called the root business unit.
>
> A business unit can own records as defined in the ownership type in
>   the metadata definition for an entity.